# Ansible merge list

Tags: list, ansible

I have two lists as below, List1 and List2. Field a is common in two lists. I need to merge and create a new list.
For an example, I have created 3 fields(like a,b,c), it may have 8 -10 fields.

List1:

```
[{"a" : "1",
  "b": "2",
  "c" : "3"
 },
 {"a" : "5",
  "b": "6",
  "c" : "7"
 },
 {"a" : "8",
  "b": "9",
  "c" : "10"
 },
 {"a" : "11",
  "b": "12",
  "c" : "13"
 },
{"a" : "20",
  "b": "212",
  "c" : "213"
 }
]
```

List2:

```
[{"a" : "1",
  "d": "22",
  "e" : "32"
 },
 {"a" : "5",
  "d": "62",
  "e" : "72"
 },
 {"a" : "8",
  "d": "92",
  "e" : "210"
 },
 {"a" : "11",
  "d": "1222",
  "e" : "1322"
 }
]
```

New list:

```
[{"a" : "1",
  "b": "2",
  "c" : "3",
  "d": "22",
  "e" : "32"
 },
 {"a" : "5",
  "b": "6",
  "c" : "7",
  "d": "62",
  "e" : "72"  
 },
 {"a" : "8",
  "b": "9",
  "c" : "10",
  "d": "92",
  "e" : "210"  
 },
 {"a" : "11",
  "b": "12",
  "c" : "13",
  "d": "1222",
  "e" : "1322"  
 }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update.

Recent filter *combine* can be applied to the lists of dictionaries. Given the lists

```yaml
  list1:
    - {a: '1', b: '2', c: '3'}
    - {a: '5', b: '6', c: '7'}
    - {a: '8', b: '9', c: '10'}
    - {a: '11', b: '12', c: '13'}
    - {a: '20', b: '212', c: '213'}
  list2:
    - {a: '1', d: '22', e: '32'}
    - {a: '5', d: '62', e: '72'}
    - {a: '8', d: '92', e: '210'}
    - {a: '11', d: '1222', e: '1322'}
```

Declare the *list3*

```yaml
  list3: "{{ list1|zip(list2)|map('combine')|list }}"
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
  list3:
    - {a: '1', b: '2', c: '3', d: '22', e: '32'}
    - {a: '5', b: '6', c: '7', d: '62', e: '72'}
    - {a: '8', b: '9', c: '10', d: '92', e: '210'}
    - {a: '11', b: '12', c: '13', d: '1222', e: '1322'}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    list1:
      - {a: '1', b: '2', c: '3'}
      - {a: '5', b: '6', c: '7'}
      - {a: '8', b: '9', c: '10'}
      - {a: '11', b: '12', c: '13'}
      - {a: '20', b: '212', c: '213'}
    list2:
      - {a: '1', d: '22', e: '32'}
      - {a: '5', d: '62', e: '72'}
      - {a: '8', d: '92', e: '210'}
      - {a: '11', d: '1222', e: '1322'}

    list3: "{{ list1|zip(list2)|map('combine')|list }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: list1|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: list2|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: list3|to_yaml
```

---

Original.

The task below does the job

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        list3: "{{ list3|default([]) + [item.0|combine(item.1)] }}"
      loop: "{{ list1|zip(list2)|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: list3
```

gives

```yaml
  list3:
  - a: '1'
    b: '2'
    c: '3'
    d: '22'
    e: '32'
  - a: '5'
    b: '6'
    c: '7'
    d: '62'
    e: '72'
  - a: '8'
    b: '9'
    c: '10'
    d: '92'
    e: '210'
  - a: '11'
    b: '12'
    c: '13'
    d: '1222'
    e: '1322'
```

---

Optionally sort the lists

```yaml
      loop: "{{ list1|sort(attribute='a')|
                zip(list2|sort(attribute='a'))|list }}"
```

and test the attribute 'a'

```yaml
    - fail:
        msg: "[ERROR] Items a do no match."
      loop: "{{ list1|sort(attribute='a')|
                zip(list2|sort(attribute='a'))|list }}"
      when: item.0.a != item.1.a
```

Comment: thank you, it worked, but in one scenario suppose when 'a' attribute is not present in list2(updated question), I still want it to be present in the list3(which will have only list1 contents).CAn you please let me know how?

Comment: There might be more options. Open a new question and make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I mean, as simple as possible; only items needed to demonstrate the problem; not more!